# SlateJS: All void elements are deleted instead of the selected one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

I tried recreating a simple mentions example here https://codesandbox.io/s/slatejs-poc-9j4f20?file=/src/App.tsx

The issue that I am facing is that, whenever I delete any void element, all of them are deleted.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `initialValue` is not correctly formatted. Your `deserialize` function returns an array containing only text nodes:

```
[
  {
    type: "text",
    children: [{ text: "My name is " }]
  },
  {
    type: "variable",
    variable: "user.name",
    children: [{ text: "" }]
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    children: [{ text: " and I am " }]
  },
  {
    type: "variable",
    variable: "user.age",
    children: [{ text: "" }]
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    children: [{ text: " old" }]
  }
]
```

While you should have a common parent node for them:

```
[
  {
    type: "paragraph",
    children: [
      { text: "My name is " },
      {
        type: "variable",
        variable: "user.name",
        children: [{ text: "" }]
      },
      { text: " and I am " },
      {
        type: "variable",
        variable: "user.age",
        children: [{ text: "" }]
      },
      { text: " old" }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo with the correct `initialValue`](https://codesandbox.io/s/slatejs-poc-forked-86sji0?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks @Arkellys for providing the solution. It works!